# VBA (Excel) - Get error number from a variable that became equal to an error

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario:

```
dim Result as variant
Result = Application.Match(string, Wb.Sheets("UD_Base").Range("UD_Base[U_ID]"), 0)
```

---

Now if i check the values of -Result- it can either be a number or an error.:
Debug.Print Result -> 1
Debug.Print result -> Error 2042

---

I can test -Result- with: IsError(result) and it gives True or False
... but even if -Result- IS an error, I cannot get its number.

**Result.Number -> Object or Type error message** comes
so seemingly i cannot use it as in **Err.Number**

**How can I get the error number of -Result- variable?
What is in this case -Result- really equal with?**

If i say If Result = ??? Then ...    when will it be true if i know that its Error 2042?
I have tested Case "Error 2042" ; Case Err ; Case Error ; Case Err(2042) ; ...
None of these showed True for -Result- when it debug.printed Error 2042

Please enlighten me guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in `Result` is of type `Error`.  So you need to compare it with an error value.  eg:

```
Result = CVErr(2042)
```

will return `True` if `Result` contains that error value

But, in order to run the test, you first have to test if `Result` contains an error type.  If not, you will get a type mis-match on the comparison statement.

You can test in a variety of ways:

```
IsError(Result)
VarType(Result) = 10
VarType(Result) = vbError
TypeName(Result) = "Error"
```

If you need to pull out the particular number, you can do it with something like

```
Mid(CStr(Result),7)
```

converting the error value to a string.

Comment: Thanks (for BOTH of you). I was a bit "afraid" of using forums, thinking that results might come only days after I needed the answer. Instead of that I got an immediate response... so my faith in forums grew a lot.! :) ;)

Comment: Response time for concise clear questions, with some thought given to the guidelines for this forum, generally get rapid responses depending on their complexity. You narrowed down your problem to a single issue; posted the appropriate code and answering your question did not require additional information than what you posted in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
Sub adam()
    Dim s As String, result As Variant
    s = "happy"
    result = Application.Match(s, Range("A:A"), 0)
    MsgBox CLng(Split(CStr(result), " ")(1))
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Based on Ron's comment, use this instead:

```
Sub adam()
    Dim s As String, result As Variant
    s = "happy"
    result = Application.Match(s, Range("A:A"), 0)
    If InStr(1, CStr(result), " ") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Match worked; result is:  " & result
    Else
        MsgBox "Match failed; error is:  " & CLng(Split(CStr(result), " ")(1))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Although unlikely to occur, that code will not differentiate between the **string** `Error 2042` and the **error** `2042`